# Odoo 10 - Execute custom model method via XMLRPC

Tags: xml-rpc, odoo-10, odoo

I am trying to execute a modle method remotely via XMLRPC. I can not find any working example to achive this in the docs:

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
'res.partner', 'check_access_rights',
['read'], {'raise_exception': False})
```

What if I want to execute the following method:

```
@api.model
def foo():
    ....
```

or this one:

```
@api.multi
def bar(self):
     ....
```

Specifically I have tried something simple as this. I extend `stock.picking` with:

```
class Picking(models.Model):
  _inherit = 'stock.picking'

  @api.model
  def test():
    print 'debug test'
    return []
```

And the following python code to connect:

```
import xmlrpclib

srv = 'http://localhost:8069'
db = 'mydb'
user, pwd = 'info@foo.com', 'password'
common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('%s/xmlrpc/2/common' % srv)
print common.version()
uid = common.authenticate(db, user, pwd, {})
print uid
api = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('%s/xmlrpc/2/object' % srv)

result = api.execute_kw(db, uid, pwd, 'stock.picking', 'test', [])
print result
```

The following error message is:

```
# python test2.py
{'server_version_info': [10, 0, 0, 'final', 0, ''], 'server_serie': '10.0', 'server_version': '10.0-20171030', 'protocol_version': 1}
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 12, in <module>
result = api.execute_kw(db, uid, pwd, 'stock.picking', 'test', [])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1243, in __call__
return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1602, in __request
verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1283, in request
return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1316, in single_request
return self.parse_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1493, in parse_response
return u.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 800, in close
raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 1: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 56, in xmlrpc_return\n    result = odoo.http.dispatch_rpc(service, method, params)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 118, in dispatch_rpc\n    result = dispatch(method, params)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 38, in dispatch\n    res = fn(db, uid, *params)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 157, in execute_kw\n    return execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper\n    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 164, in execute\n    res = execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 153, in execute_cr\n    return odoo.api.call_kw(recs, method, args, kw)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 687, in call_kw\n    return call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 669, in call_kw_model\n    context, args, kwargs = split_context(method, args, kwargs)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 296, in split_context\n    return args[pos], args[:pos], kwargs\nIndexError: tuple index out of range\n'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have an issue with this line:

`result = api.execute_kw(db, uid, pwd, 'stock.picking', 'test', [])`

As it should be:

`result = xmlrpclib.execute_kw(db, uid, pwd, 'stock.picking', 'test', [])`

Just replace `api` with `xmlrpclib`